# Scan folders with non English letters in a given directory

Tags: c++, path, directory, filesystems

here is a function written in c++ 2011 (VS); I'm using this function to get the extension and the size of every file in every directory. My problem is when there is a folder named something in non English letters, it won't open that folder to search for extensions. I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this issue.

```
void scan(path const& f)
{
    directory_iterator d(f);
    directory_iterator e;
    for (; d != e; ++d)


    {
            string ext = d->path().extension();
            _ULonglong size = file_size(d->path());
            if (is_directory(d->status())) 
                scan(d->path());
    }

}
```

Comment: I assume you're using the [Boost filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)? Also, what is your system locale (language)? What is the locale setting in your program?

Comment: #include <filesystem>

locale here("");
cout.imbue(here); //Canada

Comment: That's probably the TR2 implementation which mirrors Boost FileSystem v2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer MSalters, but is there an alternative to that?